# IScroll event for touchend/user release

Tags: angularjs, touch, iscroll

I am building a Cordova/PhoneGap app. I am using Iscroll5 (https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll) for building a crossplatform pull-to-refresh feature. Seeing this example http://www.kamrat.com/test/iScroll5/iscroll5-pull-test.html, i want something similar but without using probe, as scrolling seems jumpy with this on. Is there any event or a way to know when the user preforms a touchend? Something like a beforeScrollEnd? Or is there a way to bind touchend to iscroll-element?

I been struggling for days to create this feature to work nicely but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `touchend` event to the HTML element, not the IScroll object.

So, if you have created your IScroll using

```
var scroll = new IScroll("#content");
```

Then just add your event like this:

```
document.getElementById("content").addEventListener("touchend", function () {
    // do your refresh
}, false);
```